copy physical hard disk to dynamically allocatable virtual disk (vdi)
I have a hard drive containing ubuntu root filesystem. The drive size is 100GB but it is filled upto 20GB. I wanted to have a duplicate to use it in virtualbox. I tried to boot on a live ubuntu and use qemu-img to convert my drive to a vdi file. But it created 100GB file. dd resulted in similar file.
How can I have a vdi file that is only 20GB large and use it with virtualBox in the way that native vdi files allocate dynamic space?

I used for the other way around  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-convertfromraw
